# How to add github module to magento2 site?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

I want to create a gallery in magento2 but No free extension is avalilable . So now I am trying to install that module from github

> https://github.com/daniel-rose/magento2-gallery

I extracted that in my

> /var/html/www/magento2/app/code/infornite/Gallery/

I made this folder Gallery and in this folder full folder with code reside in a folder gallery. After that I run all three commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

but still nothing happens. I am using Ultimo paid theme . can somebody help me ?

**EDIT** : When I run this I got this error

**Fatal error:  Interface 'DR\Gallery\Api\Data\ImageInterface' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Infortis/Gallery/Model/Image.php on line 16**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According module source code and documentation, you need to place module in directory 
`/var/html/www/magento2/app/code/DR/Gallery/`

Comment: kindly check updated question EDIT section when I run it

Comment: file path in fatal error indicates that source code still located in wrong directory. Move code to right directory according module documentation, clean caches and test it.